# AngularJS directive dynamic template ng-repate not working

Tags: angularjs

I have a problem when I want to show the loops index+1 in the html template.

This is the JS code:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('emp', function($scope) {
    $scope.myNumber = 5;
    $scope.myOtherNumber = 10;
    $scope.getNumber = function(num) {
        return new Array(num);
    }
});
app.directive('test', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngRepeat',
        scope: {
            nbr: '@'
        },
       template: '<li ng-repeat="i in getNumber(myOtherNumber) track by $index"><span>{{$index+1}}</span></li>'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass parameters for the directive instead of calling a controller method like so:

```
<list-numbers numbers="[1,2,3,4,5]"></list-numbers>
```

Or may be this:

```
<list-numbers numbers="getNumber(myOtherNumber)"></list-numbers>


app.directive('listNumber', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            numbers: '='
        },
       template: '<ul><li ng-repeat="i in numbers track by $index"><span>{{$index+1}}</span></li></ul>'
    }
});
```